Joining two tables on arrays of varying length
I am trying to join two tables in BigQuery on arrays that could change in size. I have tried to illustrate it in the example below. One of the tables is called zoo (the column animals in this is an array) and the other guidelines (all columns except task_id are arrays).
The pseudocode of what i am trying is as follows. Basically i want the join to work when all elements of guidelines.if_cage_has_all_these_animals are in zoo.animals
SELECT
zoo.cage_number,
CONCAT(zoo.animals,guidelines.more_animals_to_be_added)
FROM zoo
LEFT JOIN guidelines
ON zoo.animals = guidelines.if_cage_has_all_these_animals

The zoo table can be generated in Bigquery with
SELECT
1 as cage_number,
['cats','parrots', 'dogs','ants'] AS animals union all
select
2 as cage_number,
['bears', 'jaguars', 'lions'] AS animals

and looks like this:

and the guidelines table can be produced by
SELECT
1 as task_id,
['cats', 'dogs'] AS if_cage_has_all_these_animals,
 ['rats', 'geese'] AS more_animals_to_be_added union all
select
2 as id,
['bears', 'jaguars', 'lions'] AS if_cage_has_all_these_animals,
['falcon'] AS more_animals_to_be_added union all
select
3 as id,
['parrots'] AS if_cage_has_all_these_animals,
['crow'] AS more_animals_to_be_added

and looks like

The result table will look like this:

For cage 1 both task_id 1 and 3 were used since it had cats and dogs (task_id 1) and parrots (task_id 3)

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

['cats','parrots', 'dogs','ants'] AS animals is not valid MySQL syntax. None of this looks like MySQL table structure.

Sorry, forgot to mention before that this is in Bigquery

Below is for BigQuery
with temp as (
  select cage_number, more_animals_to_be_added as animals
  from zoo z 
  join guidelines g
  on true
  where array_length(if_cage_has_all_these_animals) = (
    select count(distinct x)
    from z.animals x
    join g.if_cage_has_all_these_animals x
    using (x)
  )
)
select cage_number, array_concat_agg(animals) animals
from (select * from temp union all select * from zoo)
group by cage_number

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

